# How older is the Google Real Time Data when fetching from Google Analytics Real Time API v3?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I know Google Real Time Data provided event data that just happened. But two questions that didn't get answer anywhere are :-

1. If I fire an event from client (web, app etc), then after how much time should I fetch real time analytics data through Google Real Time Client API?
2. How much old is the data which we get from API? The events data which I get from API is at max 5 mins older? 10 mins older? or something else? To be more clear let there are following events triggered from client:-

   `<event1>` fired just now
   `<event2>` fired 1 minute before
   `<event3>` fired 2 minutes before.
   `<event4>` fired 10 minutes before

Then when I request Real Time Analytics API, will I get all three events? or some of them get lost? If lost then what is the threshold time after which event will not be counted as Real Time?

Answer (score 1):

The response from the real-time API returns information about what is going on on your website now.     What is now has never been defined officially by Google.  However in my experience its about five minutes.

How this data differs from the reporting api is huge.   The data in the reporting API hasn't completed processing for 24 to 48 hours so if you did get info from the reporting api for niw well the data is likely to change after it has been processed.

Real-time data has completed proccesing when it is returned.